# Sacola de Tarefas (Bag of Tasks) para multiplicação de Matrizes

Tags: python

Gostaria da ajuda de vocês para fazer este trabalho, tenho pouca prática em programação e preciso fazer em Python que ainda estou aprendendo.

O trabalho é o seguinte:

Este trabalho consiste em dividir o trabalho de multiplicação de matrizes em pequenas tarefas que serão distribuídas aos trabalhadores do SD.

Cada tarefa será composta por uma multiplicação linha x coluna, que será colocada
na sacola de tarefas.

Cada entidade realiza as seguintes atividades:

1. Cliente: Lê as matrizes de entrada A e B, divide em pequenas tarefas T
   (linha x coluna) e insere na Sacola cada uma das tarefas. Em seguida, coleta resultado a resultado (a medida que ficam prontos) e vai montando a matriz resultante C, que será impressa na tela ao término do processamento.
2. Sacola: Recebe as tarefas do Cliente e as enfileira em uma lista, de onde os trabalhadores retirarão as tarefas para processamento. Além disso, a sacola também recebe os resultados dos trabalhadores e os enfileira em uma outra lista de resultados, de onde o cliente retirará os resultados para montagem da matriz resultante C.
3. Trabalhador: Retira tarefas da Sacola e insere de volta resultados parciais.

O que eu fiz até agora:

Classe Cliente = lê uma linha da matriz A e uma coluna da Matriz B e envia para o sacola de tarefas.

```
import geraMatriz
import sacolaTarefas
class Cliente(object):

def main():

    a=[[1,2],
    [3,4]]

    b = [[2,3],
    [1,4]]

    print('Matriz Inicial')
    print 'A = ',a, '\nB = ', b   

    nLinhaA = len(a) #Ler quantdade linha matriz A
    nColunaA = len(a[0])# Ler quantidade coluna A
    nColunaB = len(b[0])# Ler quantidade coluna B
    nLinhaB = len(b)#Ler quantdade linha matriz B

    listaResultado = []
    soma = []
    for m in range(nColunaB):
        somaLinha = []
        for i in range(nLinhaA):
            conteudoLinhaA = []
            conteudoColunaB =[]
            for j in range(nLinhaB):
                conteudoLinhaA.append(a[i][j])#lendo linha de A 
                conteudoColunaB.append(b[j][m])# Lendo coluna B
            objSacola = sacolaTarefas.Sacola(conteudoLinhaA, conteudoColunaB)
            objSacola.listaTarefas()
main()
```

Classe Sacola = recebe  uma linha e uma coluna da matriz através do construtor e adiciona na lista.

```
import workers2
import Queue

class Sacola(object):
    def __init__(self, conteudoLinhaA, conteudoColunaB):
    self.conteudoLinhaA = conteudoLinhaA
    self.conteudoColunaB = conteudoColunaB

lista = Queue.Queue()
listaResp = Queue.Queue()

def listaTarefas(self):
    global lista 
    tarefa =  self.conteudoLinhaA, self.conteudoColunaB
    lista.put(tarefa)
    return lista

resp = workers2.Worker(listaTarefas())
```

Classe Worker = recebe a lista de tarefas e distribui para 4 processos executarem a multiplicação de uma linha por uma coluna.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
TRABALHADORES = 4
class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, lista):
        self.lista = lista 

    def multMatriz(self, lista):
        for x in lista:#Para cada tarefa da lista que consiste em uma linha e uma coluna da matriz
            for i in range(len(x)):#Quantidades de elementos de uma linha da matriz salva na lista
                result = 0
                for j in range(len(x[0])):# j varia de 0 ate a quantidade de elementos de uma linha/coluna a ser multiplicada
                    result += x[0][j] * x[1][j] # multiplica os elementos da linha da matriz pelos elementos da coluna a outra matriz
                    return result#resultado da multiplicacao de somente uma linha por uma coluna

    pool = Pool(processes=TRABALHADORES)
    pool.map(multMatriz, self.lista)
```

Não sei se estou fazendo da melhor forma mais foi o que consegui pensar.

Uma dúvida, como faço para passar "lista" como parâmetro em:

```
pool.map(multMatriz, self.lista)
```

Retorna o seguinte erro:

```
pool.map(multMatriz, self.lista)
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

Comment: Amigo deve ser por que você chamou as funções sem estar dentro de outra função da classe Worker.